# Add "mil"and "bil" to large numbers, and rounding

Tags: javascript

I have made a calculator, in which I have a grand total; let's say it comes out to `1453880.45`, which I already turned to `$1,453,880.45`. I want my function to also round and add *mil* or *bil* (for million and billion) to the end of it.

E.g. the previous number `$1,453,880.45` should become `$1.4 mil`.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you round that to 1dp, it should be 1.5 Mil, not 1.4

Answer (score 1):

```
function milStr(num) {
    if (num > 1000000000)
        return Math.floor(num / 1000000000) + 'Bil';
    else if (num > 1000000)
        return Math.floor(num / 1000000) + 'Mil';
    else if (num > 1000)
        return Math.floor(num / 1000) + 'K';
}
```

Comment: `floor` can be substituted with `round` here, to round up after `.5`.

Comment: This actually outputs 1 Mil for the OPs input. Math.floor completely strips the decimals

Answer (score 1):

This is a way you can display Millions.

```
"$" + (""+1453880.45/1000000).substr(0,3) + " Mil";
```

Or, if you want to achieve rounding as well, you can use `toFixed()`

```
"$" + (1453880.45/1000000).toFixed(2) + " Mil"; //Will output $1.45 Mil
```

Formatting Billions and Thousands has been left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and you can add more names ie. tri if you like.

```
function format(num){
    var val = num, i=0,
        suffix = ["", " k", " mil", " bil"];
    while(val >= 1000){
        val = val/1000;
        i++;
    }
    return val.toFixed(1) + suffix[i];
}
```